# How does excel manage to correctly decode this file contents?

Tags: microsoft-excel, utf-8, ansi, toad

I start with an excel file with the contents in each row:

```
TEST
çığ
öğö
çüş
```

Then I export this file as a CSV file and save it as `ANSI` format (which from what I have read is same as `US-ASCII`). When I try to open it with excel again, it correctly decodes the characters. If I import this file to a program like `Toad` (Oracle DB client) I get garbage as expected. How is it possible that Excel is able to correctly deocode these characters while others cannot ?

Answer (score 1):

ANSI format does not mean US-ASCII. It means that the file is saved in one of the [ANSI Code pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page). Depending on your locale the default codepage might be different. Your text was probably encoded in the Windows-1254 codepage.